# Check if directed graph is strongly connected using adjacency list

Tags: java, algorithm, graph

I need to find out if given adjacency list (int[][]) is describing a strongly connected graph.
I am failing a few test cases with more than 2 nodes in the graph.
for example adjlist = new int[][] {{ 1 },{ 2 },{ 0 },}; meaning that node 0 (first in list) can connect to node 1, node 1 can connect to node 2, and node 2 can connect to node 0.
I tried this:

```
 public boolean allDevicesConnected(int[][] adjlist) {
     Boolean[] visited = new Boolean[adjlist.length];
     for (int i = 0; i < adjlist.length; i++) {
         for (int b = 0; b < visited.length; b++) {
             visited[b] = false;
         }
         DFS1( adjlist, i, visited);
     }
        for (int j = 0; j < visited.length; j++) {
            if (visited[j] == false) {
                return false;
         }
     }   
     return true;
}
 
 private static void DFS1(int[][] adjlist, int v, Boolean[] visited) {
    visited[v] = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < adjlist[v].length; i++) {
        if (visited[i] == false) {
            DFS1(adjlist, i, visited);
        }
    }
}
```

any help would be great thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea to use a depth first search, while marking nodes as visited to determine if strongly connected is a good idea.

The first double for loop is not needed. If the graph is actually strongly connected, it does not matter at which node we start at.

Firstly, I notice that you are doing this in your DFS search:

```
visited[i] == false
```

and

```
DFS1(adjlist, i, visited);
```

That said, when you did this you are not checking the right node. You should be checking not the index i, but rather the actual value of the node stored at index i.

I edited your code to use this idea:

```
public boolean allDevicesConnected(int[][] adjlist){
    boolean[] marked = new boolean[adjlist.length];  // Default is set to false  

    DFS_helper(0, adjlist, marked);

    for(boolean b : marked)
        if(b == false) return false;

    return true;
}

public void DFS_helper(int node, int[][] adjlist, boolean[] marked){
    marked[node] = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < adjList[node].length; i++) {
        int dest = adjlist[node][i];
        if(marked[dest] == false)
            DFS_helper(dest, adjlist, marked);
    }

}
```

Comment: sorry i did not explain clearly enough. what i have is an adjacency list. so for example: adjlist = new int[][] { { 1 }, { 2 }, { 0 }, };. meaning that node 0 can connect to node 1, node 1 can connect to node 2, and node 2 can connect to node 0. not a adjacency matrix as above. thank you

Comment: Ok let me edit the answer to account for this, feel free to add that information into the original question too.

Comment: im not sure if it is a typo, but in the all devices connected method it has: if b==false, return false. and then after that it returns false again. is this meant to be true instead?

Comment: Yes you are correct.  Also, I have been flip-flopping my answer here numerous times but I have finally landed somewhere close to where I began.  If I need to edit the answer again Ill remove it and repost it to avoid confusion.

Comment: yes it works now, thankyou so much i have been struggling with this for a while now and you have fixed it so quickly. you are a champion!